# why is XLinq reformatting my XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am using XLinq (XML to Linq) to parse a xml document and one part of the document deals with representing rich-text and uses the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute to preserve whitespace within the rich-text element.

The issue I'm experiencing is that when I have a element inside the rich-text which only contains a sub-element but no text, XLinq reformats the xml and puts the element on its own line. This, of course, causes additional white space to be created which changes the original content.

Example:

```
<rich-text xml:space="preserve">
    <text-run><br/></text-run>
</rich-text>
```

results in:

```
<rich-text xml:space="preserve">
    <text-run>
        <br/>
    </text-run>
</rich-text>
```

If I add a space or any other text before the `<br/>` in the original xml like so

```
<rich-text xml:space="preserve">
    <text-run> <br/></text-run>
</rich-text>
```

the parser doesn't reformat the xml

```
<rich-text xml:space="preserve">
    <text-run> <br/></text-run>
</rich-text>
```

How can I prevent the xml parser from reformatting my element?

Is this reformatting normal for XML parsing or is this just an unwanted side effect of the XLinq parser?

EDIT:
I am parsing the document like this:

```
using (var reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stream))
    return XElement.Load(reader);
```

I am not using any custom `XmlReaderSettings` or `LoadOptions`

The problem occurs when I use the `.Value` property on the text-run `XElement` to get the text value of the element. Instead of receiving `\n` which would be the correct output from the original xml, I will receive

`\n    \n`

Note the additional whitespace and line break due to the reformatting! The reformatting can also be observed when inspecting the element in the debugger or calling `.ToString()`.

Comment: Where are you observing this reformatting? Please show more code on what you are doing with this XElement.

Comment: Adding some search keywords: `XElement.Parse` adds whitespace, indentation, tabs.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```
yourXElement.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting)
```

This should solve your problem.

btw - you should also do a similar thing on load:

```
XElement.Parse(sr, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't help. I am already instructing it to preserve whitespace via the xml:space="preserve" attribute. The issue is not that it isn't preserving space but that it reformats the original xml and by doing so introduces additional whitespace. SaveOptions.DisableFormatting doesn't help either unfortunately.